# get view display only gives me Default

Tags: php, drupal, view

I want to get two different displays of a view with the following code:

```
<?php
  $view_args = array();

  $view = views_get_view('Frontpage', true);
       if (!empty($view)) {
        print $view->execute_display('Sticky' , $view_args);
        print $view->execute_display('News' , $view_args);
  }

?>
```

but i only get the default display? whats wrong? i cant find any hint in the drupal documentation
im using drupal6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 'Sticky' or 'News', `execute_display` will accept a display id (like 'page_1'), not a display name.

GIYF : http://drupal.org/node/567214